# VHDL Mysterious Red Waves

Tags: vhdl, logical-operators

I'm building a "package sorter" which basically takes a weight, and adds it to a specific group based on that weight, and keeps track of how many weights (aka packages) are in each group using a simple counter. However, when running my test bench, I'm encountering weird red waves that shouldn't really be there:
[image]

Now I have read that these could mainly result from assigning the same signal a value from two different locations, however I've been failing to find the culprit and the deadline is nearing. Here is my code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity packageSorter is
    port (clk,reset: in std_logic;
        weight: in std_logic_vector (11 downto 0);
        grp1: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        grp2: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        grp3: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        grp4: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        grp5: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        grp6: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        
        currentGrp: out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0))   ;


end packageSorter;


architecture beh of packageSorter is

    signal count1 : integer range 0 to 256;
    signal count2 : integer range 0 to 256;
    signal count3 : integer range 0 to 256;
    signal count4 : integer range 0 to 256;
    signal count5 : integer range 0 to 256;
        signal count6 : integer range 0 to 256;
    signal lastWeight : std_logic_vector (11 downto 0);
    signal currentWeight : std_logic_vector (11 downto 0);
    begin
    process(clk)
    begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
    if(reset = '1') then
        count1 <= 0;
        count2 <= 0;
        count3 <= 0;
        count4 <= 0;
        count5 <= 0;
            count6 <= 0;
        lastWeight <= "000000000000";
        currentWeight <= Weight; -- intermediate signal equal to input

    end if;

  if to_integer(unsigned(lastWeight)) = 0 then --IF LAST WEIGHT WAS 0

            if to_integer(unsigned(weight)) = 0 then
                    currentGrp <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(0,3));
            elsif to_integer(unsigned(weight)) >= 1 and to_integer(unsigned(weight)) <= 200 then --group 1
                    count1 <= (count1 + 1);
                    currentGrp <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(1,3));
                    lastWeight <= weight;
            elsif to_integer(unsigned(weight)) >= 201 and to_integer(unsigned(weight)) <= 500 then --group 2
                    count2 <= (count2 + 1);
                    currentGrp <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(2,3));
                    lastWeight <= weight;
            elsif to_integer(unsigned(weight)) >= 501 and to_integer(unsigned(weight)) <= 800 then --group 3
                    count3 <= (count3 + 1);
                    currentGrp <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(3,3));
                    lastWeight <= weight;
            elsif to_integer(unsigned(weight)) >= 801 and to_integer(unsigned(weight)) <= 1000 then --group 4
                    count4 <= (count4 + 1);
                    currentGrp <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(4,3));
                    lastWeight <= weight;
            elsif to_integer(unsigned(weight)) >= 1001 and to_integer(unsigned(weight)) <= 2000 then --group 5
                    count5 <= (count5 + 1);
                    currentGrp <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(5,3));
                    lastWeight <= weight;
            elsif to_integer(unsigned(weight)) >= 2000 then --group 6
                    count6 <= (count6 + 1);
                    currentGrp <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(6,3));
                    lastWeight <= weight;
            end if;
        
 elsif to_integer(unsigned(lastWeight)) /= 0 then

            lastWeight <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(Weight) + unsigned(lastWeight));
            currentWeight <= lastWeight; --currentWeight is whatever the input weight is

            if to_integer(unsigned(currentWeight)) = 0 then
                    currentGrp <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(0,3));
                    lastWeight <= "000000000000";
            elsif to_integer(unsigned(currentWeight)) >= 1 and to_integer(unsigned(currentWeight)) <= 200 then --group 1
                    currentGrp <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(1,3));
            elsif to_integer(unsigned(currentWeight)) >= 201 and to_integer(unsigned(currentWeight)) <=500 then --group 2
                    currentGrp <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(2,3));
            elsif to_integer(unsigned(currentWeight)) >= 501 and to_integer(unsigned(currentWeight)) <= 800 then --group 3
                    currentGrp <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(3,3));
            elsif to_integer(unsigned(currentWeight)) >= 801 and to_integer(unsigned(currentWeight)) <= 1000 then --group 4
                    currentGrp <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(4,3));
            elsif to_integer(unsigned(currentWeight)) >= 1001 and to_integer(unsigned(currentWeight)) <= 2000 then --group 5
                    currentGrp <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(5,3));
            elsif to_integer(unsigned(currentWeight)) >= 2001 then --group 6
                    currentGrp <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(6,3));
            end if;
            
        end if;

    end if;


    end process;
    grp1 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(count1,8));
    grp2 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(count2,8));
    grp3 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(count3,8));
    grp4 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(count4,8));
    grp5 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(count5,8));
    grp6 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(count6,8));

end beh;
```

It is definitely worth noting that even the clock signal (Which triggers the counter on a rising edge) goes red and corrupt as shown in the first wave, despite not having any assignments to it. I have included my test bench as well as I'm not sure if the issue could be stemming from there but I doubt that is the case

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity packageSorter_TB is
end packageSorter_TB;

architecture tb of packageSorter_TB is
    component packageSorter
    port (clk,reset: in std_logic;
          weight: in std_logic_vector (11 downto 0);
          grp1: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
          grp2: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
          grp3: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
          grp4: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
          grp5: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
          grp6: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
          
          currentGrp: out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0));
    end component;

    signal TB_clk: std_logic := '0';
    signal TB_reset :  std_logic := '0';
    signal TB_weight : std_logic_vector (11 downto 0) := "000000000000";
    signal TB_grp1, TB_grp2, TB_grp3, TB_grp4, TB_grp5, TB_grp6 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "00000000";
    signal TB_currentGrp: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := "000";

    begin
      UUT : packageSorter port map ( clk => TB_clk, reset => TB_reset, weight => TB_weight, grp1 => TB_grp1, grp2 => TB_grp2, grp3 => TB_grp3,
                                     grp4 => TB_grp4, grp5 => TB_grp5, grp6 => TB_grp6, currentGrp => TB_currentGrp);
    TB_clk <= '0' after 10 ns;
      TB_clk <= '1' after 20 ns;
      TB_weight <= "000011111010" after 30 ns; --250
      TB_clk <= '0' after 40 ns, '1' after 50 ns;
      TB_weight <= "000000000000" after 60 ns; 
      TB_clk <= '0' after 70 ns, '1' after 80 ns;
      TB_weight <= "000111111010" after 90 ns; --506
    
 --     TB_clk <= '0' after 35ns;
 --     TB_clk <= '1' after 40ns;
 --     TB_weight <= "000100000000" after 40ns; 
 --     TB_clk <= '0' after 45ns;
 --     TB_clk <= '1' after 50ns;
 --     TB_weight <= "000000000000" after 50ns; 
 --     TB_clk <= '0' after 55ns;
 --     TB_clk <= '1' after 60ns;
 --     TB_weight <= "000111110100" after 60ns;
 --     TB_clk <= '0' after 65ns;
 --     TB_reset <= '1' after 70ns;
 --     TB_clk <= '1' after 75ns;
 --     TB_weight <= "000000000001" after 75ns;
      
          end tb;
```

I appreciate anybody that even read through these blocks of code. Thanks.

Comment: `tb_clk` has multiple concurrent assignements to it (4 in total). `TB_weight` also has 3 concurrent assignments to it. Did you mean for those assignemnts to be done inside a process?

Comment: My entity's purpose is to take a weight input on every active clock signal (0 -> 1), so what I am trying to do is first trigger the active edge by setting the clock to 0 then 1 (which will take weight = 0), and then set the weight to 250, followed by again triggering an active edge so that this weight will be taken. Is this wrong?

Comment: A concurrent assignment elaborates into a sequential assignment inside a process statement. Each process that assigns a signal has a driver for it. Driver values are resolved (and can produce 'X's).  Your testbench stimuli need to be produced sequentially all in the same process where you'd have only one driver. Delays are from the current simulation time.

Comment: The "drivers" command (in the console window) will list all drivers on any signal you ask.